# Creating a UIImageVIew with the exact size of an image

Tags: ios, uiimageview

How is the size detected from an image and then use that size to create a UIImageView, perfectly fitting the image inside?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just create the UIImageView like this:

```
UIImageView *aImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]];
```

So the ImageView has the size of the image. From the Documentation of UIImageView:

> This method adjusts the frame of the receiver to match the size of the specified image. It also disables user interactions for the image view by default.

I hope my answer helps you. :-D

Sandro

Comment: Nice1 Sandro, will try it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here no need to set the frame size when we use the image in imageView

```
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

ImageView will automatically takes the size of image.